# Save search from Dev Tools

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I'm a new user to Kibana 5.3.

I'm working on a search in "Dev Tools" panel. When I'm done with the code of the search, how do I save this search so it becomes available later for visualizations etc.?

Answer (score 0):

it saves in local storage, so as long as you don't clear your browser cache, you're OK. You CAN, however append something like `?load_from=http://my-app/assets/kibana.json` to your kibana URL and specify a json file which you save your queries to. This way you can possibly version them as well.

For example, I keep my queries in an assets folder for the project I'm working on and make sure I sync the 2 in case I have to blow away my cache. Note that a JSON linter will complain about the CURL-esque statements if you copy & save to that file.

Comment: Where exactly does it save in the local storage? The URL for the Kibana that I was accessing changed and now I can't access my old queries and I would like to recover them.

Comment: @Mike Is it possible to pass a file from local storage to `load_from` option? In the example above, you are using an HTTP link, I would like to use file from the local system.